# Prevent GDI leaks in dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, gdi, resource-leak

There is a graphical library which is used in a dll, loaded into a process. It seems the library leaks (during loading/unloading several times GDI handle count in the Process Explorer property dialog constantly grows for the whole process).

Is there a way to store all GDI handles created by the dll in a process to delete them all after the dll is unloaded? Say, hook CreateBitmap() and so on? But how to determine whether the resource is being created by our dll, not the process itself?

Regards,

Comment: I'm sure the DLL exposes functions that must be called to initialize and uninitialize the library. Are you calling those? Other than that, you'll have to fix the library. See [Debugging a GDI Resource Leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak.aspx) for helpful advice.

Comment: @IInspectable Yep, they are called. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to store all GDI handles created by the dll in a process to delete them all after the dll is unloaded? Say, hook CreateBitmap() and so on? But how to determine whether the resource is being created by our dll, not the process itself?

No. You are going to need to fix this problem at source. If the DLL really is leaking handles, you have to fix the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

A way to close all handles open by the DLL and release all resources is in usage of a separate process which loads the DLL and terminates after the DLL is unloaded. So you can evaluate which effort is larger: to fix the DLL, to find another DLL (which doesn't leak and perhaps doesn't have many other pitfalls), or to implement inter-process communication to release the handles and still use the DLL. If you choose the latter way, you could transfer the bitmaps drawn between the processes using a block of shared memory, synchronize using named events, etc. .

Answer (score 1):

To determine the caller you have to get stack trace for each call, look at [RtlCaptureStackBackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552119(v=vs.85).aspx).

Another way I would try to do is to modify this DLL (I assume that you have a DLL binary only, not source code: otherwise you could fix the leaks) to make it use say GDI33.DLL instead of GDI32.dll. Then you create GDI33.DLL that exports those functions that are used by that dll. GDI33.DLL forwards calls to GDI32.dll and collects GDI object handles.